# breaking the round robin for loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parallel-processing

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>

using namespace std;
static long num_steps = 100;
#define NUM 8
double step;

void main()
{
    clock_t time =clock();
    ofstream result;
    result.open ("Result.txt");
    int a[100];
    double pi, sum=0.0; 
    step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM)
    {           
        int i, ID;    
        double x, psum= 0.0; 
        int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        ID = omp_get_thread_num();   
        for (i=ID;i<= num_steps; i+=nthreads)
        {
            x = (i+0.5)*step;
            psum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        sum += psum;
    }

    pi = step * sum; 
    for (int j=0;j<100;j++)
    result<<a[j]<<endl;

    time = clock() - time;

    result << "Time Elapsed: " << (((double)time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;

    result <<"======================================================================================="<<endl;
    result.close();
}
```

The question is:
`for (i=ID;i<= num_steps; i+=nthreads)`
the following for loop execute the threads in the following order:
01234567 01234567 01234567 etc...
the assignment is to change the for loop to so threads are distributed equally and anot in rounded way. first the zeroes then ones then twos .... then the sevens
How should I change the forloop?

Comment: What do you mean by "Equally distributed and anot in rounded way. first the zeroes then ones then twos then the sevens"?

Comment: consider you have 3 threads and the for loop goes up to 12
the threads are executed according to round robin: 012 012 012 012
However I want to change the for loop statement so the threads are executed in the following order: 0000 1111 2222

Answer (score 0):

you must use some kind of thread synchronization for that ...
You tag Visual studio so I assume Windows platform ...

Lately this become my favourite:

```
// init
CRITICAL_SECTION hnd;
InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&hnd,0x00000400);

// start lock
EnterCriticalSection(&hnd);
// stop lock
LeaveCriticalSection(&hnd);

// exit
DeleteCriticalSection(&hnd);
```

But there are many other ways.

- You can also try to make your own locks or lock-less threads
- but be aware of that in newer OS like Windows 7 is different process sheduler
- and have tendency to be **crazy**
- with what i mean 100% working lock-less code on previous OS-es is now choppy or freezing
- so i prefer to use OS locks.

**If you use locks wrongly you risk to lose any benefit of multi-threaded speed-up.**

If you just worry about that your solution does not compute threads on the same time
not parallel but serial in your case than it can be caused by this:

1. processing time granularity.

   - any sheduled task is divided to chunks of time.
   - If your task is too short then it is done sooner then the other task even begin execution.
   - to test that try bigger payload (compute time > few seconds)
   - enlarge number of cycles greatly
   - add Sleep(time ms) to have longer computation time
   - if the output will be mixed then it was it
   - if not then you are still under granularity boundary
   - or your multi-thread code is wrong
2. wrong multi-thread code

   - are you shore your threads are created/running at the same time ?
   - or do you synchronize to something wrong ? (like till the end of previous task)
   - also some compilers do a big deal of volatile variables (add locks to it what sometimes do very weird things ... I stumped on it many times but mostly on MCU platforms and Eclipse)
3. Single core

   - on some cases if you have just 1 CPU/Core/Computer for processing
   - or just setted affinity mask to single CPU
   - on some algorithms windows shedulers do not shedule the CPU time evenly
   - even regardless the process/thread priority/class
   - something similar appears sometimes on Windows 7 even for more CPUs ...
   - especially with code mixed with Kernel mode code

To play with granularity you can use his:

```
// obtain OS time capabilities
TIMECAPS tim; 
timeGetDevCaps(&tim,sizeof(tim));

// set new granularity
if (timeBeginPeriod(time ms)!=TIMERR_NOERROR) log("time granularity out of range");

// return to previous hranularity
timeEndPeriod(time ms ... must be the same as beginperiod);out of range");
```

**PS.** Very good stuf about this is here:

http://bitflipgames.com/2011/05/09/multithreaded-programming-part-1-the-critical-section-lock/
http://bitflipgames.com/2011/05/17/multithreaded-programming-part-2-multiple-readersingle-writer-lock/
http://bitflipgames.com/2011/05/20/multithreaded-programming-part-2-5-mrsw-lock-code/
http://bitflipgames.com/2011/05/25/multithreaded-programming-part-3-going-lockless/